# Is it possible in "document list" to control whether a user permitted to see the document,Different permissions for each document in the list

Tags: sharepoint

is it possible in "document list" to control whether a user  primted to see the document,
Different permissions for each  document in the list
is it possible to do from in side a wepart code or from a workflow code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can give individual permissions for every document in a list. To do this, you have to break up role inheritance with the [BreakRoleInheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee550474.aspx)() method on the [SPListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem_members.aspx).

You can then set new individual permission for this item. Have a look at [this blog post](http://howtosharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/10/programmatically-add-delete-modify-item.html) it describes how to change permissions via code.

So remove the permissions for an item and re-add them only for the user how should be able to see or edit them. Using different RoleDefinitions you can decide what an user is able to do with the document. Only see it or also be able to edit it.